# AppDelegate send response swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, appdelegate, google-signin

I work with google signIn Api, when I click on my login button on my first view I got the google webview page, I can log myself and get my data, after I use performe for segue to access to the 2nd view.
When I try to logout in the the 2nd view, he print my string "deco", and I go back to my first page. But when I try to log myself again, he crash with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'uiDelegate must either be a
>   |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:|
>   and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from
>   |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'

I think the logout function didn't work, and also I don't think use performe for segue in the appDelegate is the best methode, do you make it with something else ? (Expect Notification)

My firstViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}}
```

In my second view I have the same thing, only change is         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()

My appDelegate contain

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        var configureError : NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        if (configureError != nil)
        {
                print("We have an error ! \(configureError)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Google ready sir !")

        }
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(
            url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)
    {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.accessToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            print("userId =>\(userId)")
            print("idToken =>\(idToken)")
            print("fullName =>\(fullName)")
            print(" familyName=>\(familyName)")
            print(" givenName=>\(givenName)")
            print("email =>\(email)")
            print("info => \(user.authentication)")
            guard let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController
                else {
                    return
            }
            rvc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "test", sender: nil)



        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }



    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)
    {
        print("Deco")
    }
    // Other func not usefull
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you declared both your `ViewController` and your `AppDelegate` as implementing `GIDSignInUIDelegate` but you only put the implementation in `AppDelegate`.

You should decide whether you want the implementation in one or the other, and only declare the protocol supported there.  My guess is that you are crashing because the `ViewController` is the actual delegate:

```
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
```

but it doesn't have the required methods.  If you look at the [Google docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift), you can see that it recommends you implement in the `AppDelegate`.  This contains a number of steps.  The first step is the set the `uiDelegate` to your AppDelegate instance instead.  Something like:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? GIDSignInUIDelegate
```

Then add the implementation:

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
  withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
      // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
      let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
      let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
      let fullName = user.profile.name
      let givenName = user.profile.givenName
      let familyName = user.profile.familyName
      let email = user.profile.email
      // ...
    } else {
      print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
  withError error: NSError!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When I don't write  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self in my view controller, I got a crash with the same message, but I can not log even once